# The role of Axiom Schema of Replacement in the proof of Transfinite Recursion Theorem

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation, transfinite-recursion

> **Transfinite Recursion Theorem:**
>
> Let $G:V\to V$ be a class function. Then there is a unique function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $$\forall \alpha\in \operatorname{Ord}:F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$$

---

I found that the proof of this theorem often follows:

1. First, it proves that

> For all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$, there exists a unique function $f_{\alpha}$ that satisfies
>
> (1) $\operatorname{dom}f_{\alpha} = \alpha+1$
>
> (2) $\forall \beta\le\alpha:f_{\alpha}(\beta) = G(f_{\alpha}\restriction\beta)$

2. Second, it defines $F$

> For all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$, $F(\alpha):=f_{\alpha}(\alpha)$.

3. It proves that $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set with the following reasoning

> We have $F\restriction\alpha=\{\langle \beta,F(\beta)\rangle\mid \beta<\alpha\}$, so by Axiom of Schema Replacement, $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set.

---

My questions:

1. Of my understanding, After define $F$ by $\forall\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}:F(\alpha):=f_{\alpha}(\alpha)$. I think I've finished our task, which is to define $F$.

I'm unable to understand why the proof goes on to prove that $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$.

2. Of my understanding, $F$ is a function and $F\restriction\alpha$ is a restriction on $F$ and thus is a set.

I'm unable to understand what is the role of Axiom of Schema Replacement here.

Thank you so much for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you prove that $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set otherwise? This is *literally* a way to formulate the Replacement axiom schema: a class function restricted to a set is a set.

The point is that if you want to argue that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$, then you need to prove that $F\restriction\alpha$ is in the domain of $G$, or in other words, a set. Arguably, you could prove that $F\restriction\alpha+1=f_\alpha$, but this too will require you to appeal to Replacement (or its formulation via transfinite induction).

One good way to see this is to try and recreate the proof in a setting where we know it is bound to fail. Work in $V_{\omega+\omega}$ and consider $G(x)=\omega+n$  if $x\in V_{\omega+n+1}\setminus V_{\omega+n}$, or if $x\in V_{n+1}\setminus V_n$, and otherwise $G(x)=0$.

Now define by recursion this $F$. Then $F(0)=G(\varnothing)=0$, then $F(1)=G(F\restriction 1)=\omega+k$ for some appropriate $k$ (depending on your coding of ordered pairs and functions, of course). As you continue on, you realize that $F\restriction\omega$ is no longer a set. So how could you define $F(\omega)$?

Comment: Although I'm unable to understand your example (since I've just learned about Transfinite Induction/Recursion), I seem to understand your first reasoning. For the formula $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$ to work, $G(F\restriction\alpha)$ must be well-defined and thus $F\restriction\alpha$ must be in the domain of $G$. Moreover, $G$ is a function that only takes set as input. So we must prove $F\restriction\alpha$ must be a set.[...]

Comment: [...]In my proof, I've already proved that $f_{\alpha}$ is a set for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$ (by Axiom of Schema Replacement). Is it correct when I use this transformation to prove that $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set: $F\restriction\alpha=\{\langle \beta,F(\beta)\rangle\mid \beta<\alpha\}=\{\langle \beta,f_{\beta}(\beta)\rangle\mid \beta<\alpha\}=\{\langle \beta,f_{\alpha}(\beta)\rangle\mid \beta<\alpha\}=f_{\alpha}\restriction\alpha$. Since we've already know that $f_{\alpha}$ is a set. Then $f_{\alpha}\restriction\alpha$ is a set and thus $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set too.

Comment: How did you define $f_\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal?

Comment: Hi @Asaf! I did it as follows: Assume that for all $\beta<\alpha$, there exists a unique function $f_{\beta}$ that satisfies the conditions. Let $f=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}f_{\beta}$. The Axiom of Schema of Replacement asserts that $f$ is a set. Let $f_{\alpha}=f\cup\{\langle\alpha,G(f)\rangle\}$ Next we prove that $f_{\alpha}$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: So, how do you know that $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}f_\beta$ is a set?

Comment: Hi @Asaf! Let $P(\beta,f_{\beta})$ be the statement *$f_{\beta}$ satisfies (1) and (2)*. By Inductive Hypothesis, for all $\beta<\alpha$, there exists a unique function $f_{\beta}$ that satisfies (1) and (2). Then statement $P(\beta,f_{\beta})$ satisfies the requirement of Axiom Schema of Replacement. Thus $T:=\{f_{\beta}\mid P(\beta,f_{\beta}) \text{ holds for some } \beta<\alpha\}$ is a set. Then $\bigcup T$ is a set and thus $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}f_\beta=\bigcup T$ is a set.

Comment: Yes, so you see? Replacement was necessary. Depending on how exactly you prove things, you might be able to remove its usage from that last part (i.e. $F\restriction\alpha$), but it does provide us with a simple solution.

Comment: Hi @Asaf! Is it true that with my above reasoning (of course, in this approach, I must use Axiom Schema of Replacement to show that $f_{\alpha}$ is a set for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$), it follows that $F\restriction\alpha$ is a set without the need of additional justification? My bad understanding of verbal english makes me unsure so that I must ask for your confirm again.

Comment: Thank you so much @Asaf. I know that you ask such questions to ensure that I correctly understand concepts.